# ld --version Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: gcc, ld

when I am trying to run the following command, I am not sure why I am getting

```
ld --version
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

my current gcc version is

```
 gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Even I am not able to build simple hello.c file using the command

```
gcc -o hello hello.c
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped
compilation terminated.

#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```